# How to access to CameraDevice.CameraDirection if I would like to use front camera for Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, vuforia

I am working on a prototype in Unity which I would love to use the front camera of my iPhone to capture and recognizing image targets with Vuforia SDK. I found all documents but prev CameraDirection() has been deprecated since version 7.3. How can I implement this function in Unity now?

I already looked up documentations in the website library and went through the google but all the answers I could found are obsoleted.

Answer (score 1):

The [Vuforia Driver Framework](https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/driver-framework) is currently the only way to use the front camera with Vuforia Engine